# Update table via AJAX on change of number input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got a problem with an AJAX update via jQuery. I have an input field of type "number". Every time a user updates its value via up click or downclick a table gets updated via AJAX.

It works, but: If you update its value too fast, jQuery simply skips some steps and updates it only a few times. Is there any way to prevent that and trigger the AJAX function on every single click?

Also: You can add numbers into the input number by typing it in without clicking the up and down buttons. Any way to prevent that?

Comment: The current JavaScript code that makes the AJAX request would be helpful to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to disable the control that fires the AJAX until after it has successfully completed -- or failed.

If you look at the [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) documentation you'll see handlers for each:

```
// disable the up and down UI elements here, re-enable in the .always() function
var jqxhr = $.post("example.php", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.done(function() { alert("second success"); })
.fail(function() { alert("error"); })
.always(function() { alert("finished"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the input using:

```
<input type="text" disabled>
```

As for your ajax problem, a partial solution is to disable both buttons using:

```
beforeSend: {
disable buttons
}
complete: {
enable buttons
}
```

However there probably are a few better ways to acomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

or maybe you could do something like that

```
@Ajax.BeginForm("Details","Item",
        new AjaxOptions
        { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId ="searchResults",
        InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace})

<h2> Search Your Jazz </h2>
<h2>
    Item ID: @Html.TextBox("search")<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Details"/>
</h2>
@{ Html.EndForm();}
<br/>
<div id="searchResults">
```